# A fractional trig integral $ \int \frac{ \cos^6 x }{ \sin^2 x } dx $

Tags: integration, trigonometry, solution-verification

Below is a problem I did. I am not sure if my solution is right or not. Is it right? It also seems to me that there should be an easier way to do the integration.

Problem:
Evaluate the following integral:
$$ \int \frac{ \cos^6 x }{ \sin^2 x } \ dx $$

Answer:

Let $I$ be the integral we are trying to evaluate.
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \dfrac{ \cos^4 x ( 1 - \sin^2 x) }{\sin^2} \,\, dx
 = \int \dfrac{ \cos^4 x }{ \sin^2 x} \,\, dx - \int \cos^4 x \,\, dx \\
\int \dfrac{ \cos^4 x }{ \sin^2 x} \,\, dx &= \int \dfrac{ \cos^2 x (1 - \sin^2 x) }{\sin^2 x} \,\, dx \\
\int \dfrac{ \cos^4 x }{ \sin^2 x} \,\, dx &= \int \dfrac{ \cos^2 x }{\sin^2 x } \,\, dx - \int \cos^2 x \,\, dx \\
\int \dfrac{ \cos^2 x }{\sin^2 x }  &= \int \cot^2 x \,\, dx = \int \csc^2 x \,\, dx - \int \,\, dx \\
\end{align*}
Recall that:
$$ \int \csc^2 x \,\, dx = - \cot x + C $$
\begin{align*}
\int \dfrac{ \cos^2 x }{\sin^2 x }  &= \int \cot^2 x \,\, dx = -\cot x - x - C_1 \\
\int \cos^2 x \,\, dx &= \int \dfrac{1}{2} \,\, dx + \int \dfrac{ \cos(2x) }{2} \,\, dx \\
\int \cos^2 x \,\, dx &= \dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{\sin{2x}}{4} + C_2 \\
\int \dfrac{ \cos^4 x }{ \sin^2 x} \,\, dx &= -\cot x - x - \dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{\sin(2x)}{4} + C_3 \\
\int \dfrac{ \cos^4 x }{ \sin^2 x} \,\, dx &= -\cot x + \dfrac{\sin(2x)}{4} - \dfrac{3x}{2} + C_3 \\
\end{align*}
Now, I need to find:
$$ \int \cos^4 x \,\, dx $$
\begin{align*}
\int \cos^4 x \,\, dx &= \int \left( \dfrac{ 1 + \cos(2x)}{2}\right) ^2 \,\, dx \\
\int \cos^4 x \,\, dx &= \int \dfrac{1}{4} + \cos(2x) + \cos^2(2x) \,\, dx \\
\int \cos^4 x \,\, dx &= \int \dfrac{1}{4} + \cos(2x) + \dfrac{ 1 + \cos(2x)}{2} \,\, dx \\
\int \cos^4 x \,\, dx &= \int \dfrac{3}{4} + \dfrac{3 \cos(2x)}{2} \,\, dx \\
\int \cos^4 x \,\, dx &= \dfrac{3}{4}x + \dfrac{3 \sin(2x)}{4} + C_4 \\
I &= -\cot x + \dfrac{\sin(2x)}{4} - \dfrac{3x}{2} - \left(  \dfrac{3}{4}x + \dfrac{3 \sin(2x)}{4} \right)  + C
\end{align*}
The answer is:
$$ I = -\cot x - \frac{\sin(2x)}{2} - \frac{9x}{4} + C $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes I found. First,

$$\int\frac{\cos^{4}\left(x\right)}{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}dx \neq -\cot\left(x\right)+\frac{\sin\left(2x\right)}{4}-\frac{3x}{2},$$

but rather

$$\int\frac{\cos^{4}\left(x\right)}{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}dx = -\cot\left(x\right)-\frac{\sin\left(2x\right)}{4}-\frac{3x}{2},$$

so I think you forgot to distribute a negative (I checked on Desmos by differentiating that integral's answer and got the exact integrand back).

The second is that

$$\left(\frac{1+\cos\left(2x\right)}{2}\right)^{2} \neq \frac{1}{4}+\cos\left(2x\right)+\cos^{2}\left(2x\right),$$

but rather

$$\left(\frac{1+\cos\left(2x\right)}{2}\right)^{2} = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{\cos\left(2x\right)}{2}+\frac{\cos^{2}\left(2x\right)}{4}.$$

I think that should clarify things. :D

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, with $3\sin^2 x-\sin^4 x=\frac98-\cos2x-\frac18\cos 4x$
\begin{align}
 \int \dfrac{ \cos^6 x }{ \sin^2 x } dx 
=& \int \frac{ (1-\sin^2x)^3 }{ \sin^2 x }  dx 
=\int \frac1{\sin^2x} -3 +3\sin^2 x-\sin^4 x\ dx\\
=&\int \frac1{\sin^2x} -\frac{15}8-\cos2x-\frac18\cos4x\ dx\\
=&-\cot x -\frac{15}8x-\frac12\sin2x-\frac1{32}\sin4x+C
\end{align}